# Does the League of Assassins ever assassinate people?

Tags: dc, arrowverse

The League of Assassins has been described as a group of assassins that have spent thousands of years eliminating people that were "dangerous to society". However, the only concrete activities we ever hear about are the times they destroyed entire cities.

(In fact, in some other adaptations, like the Christopher Nolan *Batman* films, they're not even called assassins, they're the League of Shadows.)

Have we heard of any actual assassinations being performed by the League of Assassins (in a medium where they are *called* Assassins)? That is, where a member of the League intentionally murders a single, prominent person.

Comment: On top of my head I do remember League of Assassins being responsible for killing Boston Brand who will become Deadman

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Assassins), assuming you're looking for comic book items as well:

> Under the direction of the organization's second known leader, the villainous Sensei, the League became more brutal, and rebelled against Ra's' rule. .... As The Bronze Tiger, Turner defeated Batman in personal combat while **another League operative murdered Kathy Kane** (the secret identity of Batwoman in pre-Crisis continuity, and a close personal friend of Batman's post-crisis).